# Find certain text on XMLHttpRequest response

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I have a question.
I upload a file and send from backend status message to Post response.
How can I find a certain text from response?
I tried in that way but unsuccessfully. It gives me true on if ($(response).find($('[Failed'))) and if ($(response).find($('[NO ERROR]'))) .

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("fileToUpload", document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0]);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'text';
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
xhr.open("POST", "SoftwareUpdate.cgi?Apply_button=software_update");
xhr.onload = function () {
    var response = this.responseText;

    if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            if ($(response).find($('[Failed')))
            {
                $('.modal-title').css('color', 'red');
                $('#myModalFailed').modal('show');
            }
            if ($(response).find($('[NO ERROR]')))
            {
                $('.modal-title').css('color', 'green');
                $('#myModalSuccess').modal('show');
            }

        }
    }
};
xhr.send(fd);
```

And this is part of my response with status :

```
<!-- Method: [POST] -->
<!-- UPGRADE_STATUS: [Failed to unpack image] -->
<!--<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">-->

<html lang="en">
<!-- Begin of common_header.template -->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

King Regards.

Comment: You tagged this with jQuery, so why aren't you using `$.ajax` ? Anyway, just send back JSON; why would you send back lots of useless HTML?

Comment: jQuery’s `find` always returns an object which is always going to be truthy. They also both don’t find a match since `"[Failed"` and `"[NO ERROR]"` are being interpreted as _selectors_ which don’t match anything from your response. You don’t need jQuery for string tests. Why not just `response.includes("[Failed")` and `response.includes("[NO ERROR]")`?

Comment: @Xufox: You should answer that... Maybe OP has no control over the CGI or doesn't want/can change it... So your `.include()` solution is good. I was on something using regex... But your idea is easier. ;)

Comment: Thanks to all of you for a quick response.
Xufox , it works for me fine.